# Why does ol.proj.transform does not work?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6, proj

I want to create a map application with EPSG code 25832 with the Openlayers framework (version 6.6.1). Therefore I used this tutorial: https://maps.omniscale.com/en/examples/openlayers3_25832. So I implemented the following code:

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Map app</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./libs/v6.6.1/css/ol.css">
        <script src='./libs/v6.6.1/build/ol.js'></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='js-map' class='map'></div>
        <script src='./main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
    // Set coordinate system
    var projname = 'EPSG:25832';
    proj4.defs (projname, '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');

    // Initialize start view with Germany as center
    var startview = new ol.View ({
        projection: projname,
        center: ol.proj.transform ([10.5, 51], 'EPSG:4326', projname),
        zoom: 6,
        minzoom: 6,
        extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([4, 46, 16, 56], 'EPSG:4326', projname)
    })

    // Initialize map
    const map = new ol.Map({
        view: startview,
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        target: 'js-map'
    })
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n is null
    er proj.js:400
    or proj.js:421
    sr proj.js:438
    init main.js:11
    EventHandlerNonNull* main.js:1
```

The mentioned line in main.js is the following one: `center: ol.proj.transform ([10.5, 51], 'EPSG:4326', projname),`. It is exactly the line out of the tutorial. Just the coordinates are different. I also tried it out with the coordinates from the example but the same error occures. Hope you can help me.

Comment: You have not registered proj4.  Add `ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);` after the `proj4.defs` line.

Comment: @Mike Exactly that was the problem. Thank you!